# NSString isEqualToString: does not equates korean language.

Tags: iphone, string, localization, comparison, unicode-string

Developing iOS5 based cocoa app, below peice of comparison works fine if localization is English, but fails if localization is Korean.

```
 //title is of type NSString

 if([title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Power",@"Power")])
```

in korean title and localized string is same visibly.

does `isEqualToString:` doesnot match Korean/unicode strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess.

I assume that it does not work in English to, but since you are using the english words in your `NSLocalizedString()` the app uses them is default and that's what make you think it works.
The problem should be elsewhere.

Check if :

```
          NSLog(@"localized power = %@",NSLocalizedString(@"Power",@"Power"));
```

returns the korean translation.

Answer (score 2):

You might get better results using NSString's localized comparison methods: `-localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, `-localizedCompare:`, or `-localizedStandardCompare:`.